# PHP: does the auto_prepend_file know of "calling script"

Tags: php, prepend

Whenever a script is executed, the auto_prepend_file is being executed before.

Now: I want to "customize" this auto file in a way that it executes differently based upon what script is being run (the one that "follows" auto_prepend or with other words, the one that auto_prepend is prepended to). Is there any way to do it or has someone a trick,  how he/she made that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have now tested on multiple environments, and i know that at least

```
$GLOBALS['_SERVER']['SCRIPT_FILENAME']
```

will hold the information you need in a normal PHP installation. Your embedded system is apparently a special case and the designers may even have scrubbed this information from PHP deliberately, to foil reverse engineering.

If my code below doesn't help you, then i don't think there is anything anyone can do to answer this specific question, without trying to reverse engineer the exact same system  .

---

I made a function that will recursively look for any files name ".php" in any global variable. Try adding this to the beginning of your auto_prepend_file:

```
function recursiveArraySearch($array,$str,$path = array(),$depth=0) {

    if ($depth>4) return;
    if (isset($path[0]) && $path[0] == 'GLOBALS') return;

    foreach ($array as $k=>$v)

        if (is_array($v)) {
            recursiveArraySearch($v,$str,array_merge($path,array($k)),$depth+1);
        } else {
            if (!is_resource($v) && strpos($v,$str) !== false) echo "\$GLOBALS['".implode("']['",array_merge($path,[$k]))."'] => $v\n";
        }

}


recursiveArraySearch($GLOBALS,'.php');
die();
```

(Note: It expects the filename it searches for, to contain lowercase '.php'.)
Then start your script and see what it shows.

When i was testing, i was looking for "testpage.php". In my case, this is what i get when run from a webserver:

```
$GLOBALS['_SERVER']['PHP_SELF'] => /testpage.php
$GLOBALS['_SERVER']['SCRIPT_NAME'] => /testpage.php
$GLOBALS['_SERVER']['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] => /var/www/html/testpage.php
$GLOBALS['_SERVER']['PATH_TRANSLATED'] => /testpage.php
```

And this is what i get from running it from command line:

```
$GLOBALS['argv']['0'] => /var/www/html/testpage.php
$GLOBALS['_SERVER']['PHP_SELF'] => /var/www/html/testpage.php
$GLOBALS['_SERVER']['SCRIPT_NAME'] => /var/www/html/testpage.php
$GLOBALS['_SERVER']['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] => /var/www/html/testpage.php
$GLOBALS['_SERVER']['PATH_TRANSLATED'] => /var/www/html/testpage.php
$GLOBALS['_SERVER']['argv']['0'] => /var/www/html/testpage.php
```

So on a default PHP, it appears that there are plenty of places to get this filename.

Comment: Sorry, on my system, the Server array does not contain such infos, when scripts run that are not invoked by browsers (which, in my case, is the vast majority.

Comment: Scripts are run from commandline then? Like  'php somefile.php'

Comment: I have no idea as how the architecture of the system is, as there is no documentation about the architecture ... It is a home automation product that runs a php server "internally" and the logic is being programmed in PHP. I program php files and start them from the  product's interface (or the events like a light-button is pressed start them). All I can say is, that in such cases, the $_server array is not filled accordingly. Seems I am kinda lost ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. You shouldn't even use auto_prepend_file if it's not necessary. Just include the file in the called script at the top. Basically it's the same like using auto_prepend_file. Just you have more flexibility.

PS: I don't even know why you guys are using auto_prepend_file. Just include the damn file at the top and you're good.

Comment: The information IS available to PHP (as shown in my answer). While i agree one shouldnt use auto_prepend in their projects, it makes good sense to do when debugging/testing/reverse-engeenering/firewalling closed-source projects or large open-source projects that you where you dont want to mess with the code and eg. have it overwritten everytime you update.